# BST pass by pointer updating

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm wondering why my pointer does not update when running the following code:

```
 void bst_insert(Node* root, int data) {

  if (root == NULL) {
    Node* n = new Node();
    n->data = data;
    n->right = NULL;
    n->left = NULL;
    root = n;
    cout << root->data << endl;
    return;
  }
```

Main:

```
int main() {

  Node* root = NULL;
  bst_insert(root, 5);
  cout << root << endl
}
```

I would expect root in main to point to the `new Node` however its still `NULL`. Why?

Comment: You copy the value of the pointer into a new variable. Then you change the value of that variable. The new value will not be seen out-side the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are passing the pointer by value, so you are changing a local pointer in `bst_insert`. Pass a reference to the pointer instead:

```
void bst_insert(Node*& root, int data) 
                     ^
```

Comment: I feel so foolish. Thank you.